# why isn't my eval turning the json string into an object

Tags: javascript, json

When I execute the eval function it doesn't turn my json response into a object it just breaks my code. I've tried parsing with prototype.js and JSON2.js to no avail some please explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inventory Management</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="call.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
            <p id="resp" >new</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">



    var xhr;
    var results=getPlants(xhr,results);
    var plants;


    function getPlants(xhr,results){
        try {
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();   
            }catch(microsoft){
            try{
                xhr=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");                
                }catch(othermicrosoft){
                    try{
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");               
                    }catch(failed){
                        xhr=false;
                        alert("ajax not supported");
                    }
                }               
        }   
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        results = xhr.responseText;                     
        }    
}
    xhr.open("GET","db_interactions.php",true);     
    xhr.send(null);
    alert("sent");
 return results;

}

plants = eval('('+results+')');

document.write(typeof(plants));
        </script>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're issuing an asynchronous request. That means the function will return even when the data isn't ready yet. But your call assumes the JSON response is ready when `getPlants` is called. Which obviously makes `results` undefined because you aren't waiting for it.

Put your

```
plants = eval('('+results+')');
document.write(typeof(plants));
```

Inside the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function to make it work, or open the connection as synchronous

```
xhr.open("GET","db_interactions.php",false);
```

By the way, **don't use `eval` to parse JSON** because code may be injected maliciously. Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: The response is coming from a trusted source, and when I print results outside of the getPlants definition it returns the proper data, all I am trying to figure out is what is wrong with how I'm using the eval function that it wont properly deserialize the data, and to serialize the data I used php_encode

Comment: You won't know whether the "trusted" source have a vulnerability elsewhere causing you a XSS. Always minimize the attack surface. Plus a JSON parser is likely faster than `eval` (on my Safari `eval` takes 36% more time to parse a JSON than `JSON.parse`).